# Good way to display charts and diagrams for users with EF, MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, charts, statistics

I am using MVC3-ViewModel with EF model first on my project.
and the view im doing right now is a page where users should see statistic displayed with charts.

Any tips and helps is appreciated on how to be able to do this kind of stuff in a good way.
Any plugins perhaps or packages?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you are asking for? Are you asking about how to display these statistics in the View, or how to get statistics out of your database model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understand, your real need is not getting the statistics data (you can do that by calling a pure SQL query or just using LINQ, its your choice), just displaying them. There're many ways to do that but using a Javascript library like Highcharts or Flot will probably be much easier than a full blown Reporting service if you don't need some advanced features. You don't need advanced Javascript knowledge, most of them are documented enough to use instantly. There're also some complementing libraries, they're simply wrappers around those libraries so that you can use them in ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC projects easier. Some examples:

Flot.Net - http://flotdotnet.codeplex.com/

Highcharts.net - http://highcharts.codeplex.com/

DotNet.Highcharts - http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would use direct SQL / stored procedure for data retrieval or even SQL server reporting services (it offers charts) for any kind of reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to really understand your SQL diagram without knowing much of your application, so for the moment I'm skipping that part.
Displaying statistics as charts can be done, quite quickly and without needing to know much of javascript, using one of the many javascript libraries that you can find for example [here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/) . In order to use this libraries you may need to integrate some AJAX functionalities in your MVC application (if it's not already the case).
I use Highcharts for my personal projects and I think it's very well done and it's easy to use, though if you are using it for a commercial purpose you need a license.